# Selenium unable to open Chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is a basic code that I am trying on Selenium:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//Users//Downloads//chromedriver");      
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        System.out.println( driver.getTitle());
}
```

But I am getting the following error. The chrome browser does not open. I guess it crashes.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}) on port 48784
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'SOURAVs-Mac-mini.local', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver                        0x0000000109ebfb59 chromedriver + 2595673
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010a573b33 chromedriver + 9624371
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000109c6f773 chromedriver + 169843
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000109c92d5b chromedriver + 314715
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000109c8fbef chromedriver + 302063
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000109c8d032 chromedriver + 290866
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000109cc0234 chromedriver + 500276
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000109cbb4f3 chromedriver + 480499
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000109c95cd6 chromedriver + 326870
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000109c96ba7 chromedriver + 330663
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000109e8db09 chromedriver + 2390793
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000109e9abcc chromedriver + 2444236
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000109e9a6ee chromedriver + 2442990
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000109e74832 chromedriver + 2287666
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000109e9b63f chromedriver + 2446911
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000109e83299 chromedriver + 2347673
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000109eb28b9 chromedriver + 2541753
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000109ec5008 chromedriver + 2617352
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20633950 _pthread_start + 224
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2062f47b thread_start + 15

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:11)
```

This was working until few weeks back, but the chrome browser was updated to the latest version. I did grab the most recent chrome driver, but I am still getting this error.
I am using Chrome version 89 with ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using Chrome version 89, please download ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23
If you are using Chrome version 88, please download ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96
If you are using Chrome version 87, please download ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88
```

Download the latest version from here

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Yes I downgraded ChromeDriver to 87.0.4280.88  and Chrome browser is also Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (x86_64). But I still get the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t%22) link.
It will surely help you.